# Finding Android Library Package Names and Versions

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm new to Android development and I'm having trouble finding a central repository for the base Android packages that are used in the Gradle build system. For instance, in Android Studio my new project's `build.gradle` contains:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Where can I find the full package name and current version for something like the RecyclerView Fragment? I've found the JavaDocs page for it but it doesn't seem to show the package name or the version that I should be using. I've also looked on Maven Central for `com.android.*` packages and found nothing and tried to find whatever "JCenter" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have most of them. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html

Usually when you need something like this just google "RecyclerView gradle" and open developer.android.com result page.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I somehow missed this page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All support library package Names and Versions can be find inside your SDK package

```
Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support
```

If you don't have these, just open Android SDK through Android Studio ,Tab to SDK Tools, and checked Support Repository this will download all artifact from repository and save into support folder.

Comment: I have this checked and installed. Am I supposed to use Maven to browse this somehow?